# Custom transclusion function within directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom transclusion function that I use to move specific pieces of html to specific places in a directives template. The current transclusion function while awesome, is limited in that I can only drop things into one location. I have different pieces that need to go to different areas. Here's my setup:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
        <div class="parentDirectiveRepeat" data-list="myList">
            <div data-transclude-ipsum>Ipsum</div>
        </div> 
        <hr>
        <div class="parentDirectiveNoRepeat" data-list="myList">
            <div data-transclude-ipsum>Ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my two directives templates:

```
parentDirectiveRepeat: <div>Parent Directive<div data-ng-repeat="item in list">repeater<div data-transclude-ipsum-destination></div></div></div>
parentDirectiveNoRepeat: <div>Parent Directive<div data-transclude-ipsum-destination></div></div>
```

And the commonly shared controller between both of them:

```
function directiveController($scope, $element, $transclude, $compile){
    var ipsumDestination = angular.element($element[0].querySelectorAll("div[data-transclude-ipsum-destination]"));

    $transclude(function(clone){
        var ipsum = csFncFindElement(clone, "data-transclude-ipsum");
        ipsumDestination.append(ipsum);
    });   
}
```

So, here's the output:

```
Parent Directive
repeater
repeater
repeater
-------------
Parent Directive
Ipsum
```

The problem is, that the output should really be

```
Parent Directive
repeater
ipsum
repeater
ipsum
repeater
ipsum
-------------
Parent Directive
Ipsum
```

Here's the **jsFiddle** of the entire process: http://jsfiddle.net/uBsbC/1/

Through various tests, I've determined that when I'm using the $transclude function the data-ng-repeat has already wired up and finished. Is there a way for me to tell it not to let it's children wire up and wait until after this parent directive has gone through?